How to install older curl versions on windows with vcpkg
I'm trying to use vcpkg to install curl with vcpkg install curl[libssh,openssl]:x64-windows-static-release but it always seems to install the latest versions of libssh/zlib/openssl.
How can I ask it to install specific versions? I need to install specific older versions of each library.
I tried modifying the json that contains the version numbers, but then the check against the sha number failed.

Actually it seems if I checkout the right commit from vcpkg then I'll be getting the right ports for the library versions I want.
Just gotta make sure to find the commits at which each library version was updated to the version i want. Then get a matching vcpkg commit that will contain those ports or simply get the ports themselves.
